# Run Elastic Search on IIS (windows)

Tags: iis, indexing, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to configure elastic search to run on my windows 7 machine. I have successfully installed the service.

However i am trying to browse http://localhost:9200/. The Browser returns the page is not available.

I am wondering if we can configure it to run on IIS Server, As we can host kibana on it. (https://blog.basefarm.com/blog/how-to-install-logstash-on-windows-server-2012-with-kibana-in-iis/)

Comment: you have to start the service, either from elasticsearch/bin directory and run `service.bat start` from the command prompt, or run `service.bat manager` to bring up the service GUI so you can click `Start` and also make the service start up `Automatically`.

Comment: yes this is true, i forgot to start the service after the computer has restarted.